# Rails HABTM query only returning matching associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i'm trying create a record filter on their associations. So I have creatives and they have multiple talents. I want to have av view that filters the creatives with a specific talent. But still display each creatives multiple talents in the view.

```
class Creative
  has_and_belongs_to_many :talents
end
```

Creative -> HABTM -> Talents

```
@creatives = Creative.includes(:talents, user: [:profile_image_attachment])
@creatives = @creatives.where(talents: { id: searched_talent_id })
```

The problem is that when displaying each `creative` it only returns the matching talent.

So rendering:

```
<% @creatives.each do |creative| %>
  <% creative.talents.each do |talent| %>
    <%= talent.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Only shows the talent matched by the query, not all of them. I.e. the creative has multiple talents.

If I change the code to include a call to `.all`.

```
<% @creatives.each do |creative| %>
  <% creative.talents.all.each do |talent| %>
    <%= talent.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then I do get all talents BUT the database is hit with query for each creative.
Can I avoid this? I.e. eager loading all talents in creative and not getting limited by the one i search on!?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a subquery:

```
@creatives = Creative.includes(:talents, user: [:profile_image_attachment])
        .where(
          id: Creative.joins(:talents)
                      .where(talents: { id: searched_talent_id })
        )
```

This creates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  "creatives".* FROM "creatives" 
WHERE 
  "creatives"."id" IN (
    SELECT "creatives"."id" 
    FROM "creatives" 
    INNER JOIN "creatives_talents" ON "creatives_talents"."creative_id" = "creatives"."id" 
    INNER JOIN "talents" ON "talents"."id" = "creatives_talents"."talent_id"       
    WHERE "talents"."id" = $1
  ) 
LIMIT $2
```

This only applies the WHERE clause to the subquery instead of the rows fetched by `.includes`.